# unable to find index for $geoNear query using nestjs and mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, geonear

I keep getting the "unable to find index for $geoNear query" error.  I'm using nestjs and mongoose. Below is the original code when I first got the error.  I then tried adding "this.locationModel.createIndexes({ location: "2dsphere" });"  (mongoose version of createIndex)  That didn't work either. Same error.

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Model } from "mongoose";
import { Location } from "src/types/location";

@Injectable()
export class LocationService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel("Location") private locationModel: Model<Location>
  ) {}


  async getNearbyLocations(lon, lat, pageSize, pageNum) {
    const locations = await this.locationModel
      .find({
        location: {
          $near: {
            $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lon, lat] },
            $minDistance: 0,
            $maxDistance: 20000,
          },
        },
      })
    return locations;
  }
```

Here is the location Document file

```
import { Document } from "mongoose";

export interface Location extends Document {
  description: String;
  city: String;
  state: String;
  location: {
    type: String;
    coordinates: Array<Number>;
  };
}
```

Comment: Does the index actually exist on the collection in mongod?

Comment: yes, its in the location object

Comment: I wasn't referring to it existing in the schema object, have you checked that it was actually created in the collection on the database server.

Comment: No it wasnt created

Comment: Try using [Model.syncIndexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-syncIndexes)